# to fetch data from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, view

I am using MySQL to fetch data from 2 tables.
[image]

I want to fetch value 116 from column C of table 1 by matching column B of table 1 with column H of table2. If I apply join between the two, I get row second of table 1 as a result. But I want to get value 116 by matching values between the two. How can this be achieved in MySQL?

Comment: Show the code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a simple `join`:

```
select t2.*, t1.c
from table2 t2 join
     table1 t1
     on t2.h = t1.b;
```

You just need to specify the correct columns for lining up the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

**INNER JOIN** will be good for you, like the following :

```
SELECT 
    table2.F as F, table1.A as A, table1.C as C 
FROM table2
INNER JOIN table1 
ON ( table1.B = table2.H )
```

or a **LEFT JOIN** in case C has a null value.

```
SELECT 
    table2.F as F, table1.A as A, table1.C as C 
FROM table2
LEFT JOIN table1 
ON ( table1.B = table2.H )
```